# How would a permanent stationary super-hurricane impact the weather of a nearby land mass

Tags: science-based, environment, climate, weather

How would the weather from a permanent Cat5 hurricane (specifically with sustained 500 mph winds) that spans a 2000-mile area (across the hurricane's diameter) be impacted on continents roughly 500 miles to the north, south, and east?

I know that hurricanes pull in the moisture from all around them and drop the temperatures in the oceans below them, and to a lesser extent even in the air as the pressure pulls the cooler water up into the air from the ocean below. I am not sure how far this would really extend outward though, especially for a storm this size - I think the largest storm that has ever formed on earth so far has only been approximately 1000 miles across. So, what I'm trying to figure out is whether or not the nearby continents would receive more rain, less rain, continuous rain, or possibly no rain at all. I am also trying to figure out the storm surge impact. According to several sources I found, the storm surge can impact hundreds of miles of coast line, but how far away would this start. Is 500 miles out to sea too far for the storm surge to have an impact on the continents? Or would they receive a constant storm surge on one side and not the other side of the hurricane?

For a visual representation, this is basically a super-hurricane as previously described in size and strength that sits in the middle of an ocean basin and ranges anywhere from 500 to 1000 miles from three of my primary continents on the planet, and I know it's going to impact my weather patterns, but I cannot find enough information to figure out a rough general approximation for each area. I have the basics for in close to it for the ocean itself and the basic winds and intense rain, but I need some basis for further out as it reaches the continents.

EDIT UPDATE: Thanks for all the answers. The hurricane is permanent (supernatural in origins). @elemtilas..It is close to the middle of the ocean. There is a map located here:

https://www.worldanvil.com/w/aesar-cajuncelt/map/9dcf98e3-ae1b-4916-8ee4-846ccf0aa389

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the permanent hurricane a natural feature of this world, like the big long lasting storms on gas giants?  Or is there some unnatural input of energy associated with the hurricane?  I think a natural permastorm has implications for the rest of the planet that would be different from some huge alien heat engine making an artificial hurricane/.

Comment: I apologize that I don't have the time to do the research at this moment, but a number of questions about stationary super-storms have been asked over the years, which means there's a good probability this is a duplicate. Did you search the Stack before asking your question?

Comment: You might find this interesting and relevant to your problem. A volcanic eruption could potentially generate hypercanes, or strings of hypercanes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercane#:~:text=A%20hypercane%20is%20a%20hypothetical,warmest%20ocean%20temperature%20ever%20recorded.

Comment: A permanent stationary super hurricane with continents to the north, south and east sounds rather like the Eye of Abendego in the primary Pathfinder TTRPG game world of Golarion. If this is what you are asking about then congratulations on filing off the serial numbers, if it isn't then you may want to look up the Paizo-published material on how they think it all works.

Comment: Could you add a map indicating where the storm is in relation to the continents? If the storm is "in the middle of the ocean" storm surge won't be a factor, as that really only happens as the centre of the hurricane approaches land. I also suspect that the latitude of the storm will affect the answers as well, so please indicate that too! Otherwise, really good question!

Comment: There is a novel that discusses this: Mother of Storms by John Barnes. I haven't read it in a long time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_of_Storms

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. @KerrAvon2055 wasn't aware Paizo had done this...never played Pathfinder and not fond of Paizo as a company in general.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is that the Hurricanes always lose force on landfall.  With North Atlantic Storms, these to be the United States.  While the season is from June 1st to November 30th, the most active part of the year is August-September, when winds shear from the west is at its lowest, allowing for cyclone behavior of humid air to occur.

Hurricanes lose strength rapidly as they pass over land, due to the fact that it needs a constant source of warm water evaporate to fuel the storm... Dry land... notoriously having no warm water, will cause the "fuel" to deplete faster than the over water portion can refuel it.  It's not uncommon for storms passing over Caribbean Islands to drop a whole category after the system goes back to sea.  Wind speed rarely equals length.  The longest lived tropical cyclone, the 1899 San Ciriaco hurricane, lasted just short of 28 days, most of it spent as a Tropical Storm (not even cat-1), though it's land fall was a Cat-3 in Puerto Rico.

No storm lasts forever.  Even Jupiter's Great Red Spot, an anti-cyclonic storm covering a diameter similar to that of earth, is even believed to be dying out... possibly to be no more within our lifetime... so a permanent weather feature is unlikely.  Winds change.